# R - equivalent of pip freeze (how to install all R dependencies from a file listing packages names and versions)

Tags: r, package-managers

I'm on a new project where there is R code with tons and tons of dependencies, and a specific version of R (3.1.1). When they originally wrote the code they used R's `install.package('the-package')` to download the most recent version, however now many of the dependencies have new versions which make them incompatible with the R version used (the newest versions of certain packages for instance dplyr, rcpp would require an R upgrade which is not a possibility)

From this experience R seems like it has the worst package manager - I'm coming from NPM where you specify each package and the specific version of the package needed. It is a huge pain (Going on 5+ hours) to resolve these dependencies manually, because apparently the default behavior is to always download the bleeding edge of any package. I have been relatively successful thus far, clicking the 'old sources' link on the CRAN page for the package, downloading the tars and then installing from their.. But this seems like a lot of unnecessary pain. I've had a team member follow [this guide](https://www.r-bloggers.com/list-of-user-installed-r-packages-and-their-versions/) to get a list of all the dependencies and versions I need (This at least gives me the possibility to install all the packages up front, and then proceed with trial and error, rather than resolving 50+ dependencies individually each time the build fails in my new environment).. but there is no "R, process my dependencies file" command.

- Javascript - you use NPM to install from package.json.
- Python - you can do `pip freeze` and `pip install pip_freeze.txt`, the same concept
- R - as far as I can tell, no easy way to download exactly what you need if you have specific needs like I do

This is a shell script which is easily modified to download a specific version of a package

```
#!/bin/bash
# CRAN doesn't have a version of this installable in our old R.
wget -P /tmp https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/Rcpp_0.12.5.tar.gz || { echo 'wget failed'; exit 1; }
Rscript -e "install.packages('/tmp/Rcpp_0.12.5.tar.gz', repos = NULL, type='source')" 2>&1 | tee -a rPkgInstall.log
 if egrep "non-zero exit status|Error in install.packages|^package .* is not available" rPkgInstall.log; then
    echo 'FAILED';
    exit 1;
fi
```

How can I make this an easier process for the next person who joins the team? Documentation can go a long way, but what I'm looking for is a functional package manager in R... Or a convention that allows me to do the same as `NPM install (from a package.json)` in R

Comment: go check out the checkpoint package. It will allow you to time-travel back to a specific day starting in late 2014 and get all packes in their then current versions on CRAN.

Answer (score 8):

The `packrat` package should work for your use case.  If you're using RStudio I suggest using the Packrat tool they've built into the UI, but you can also use it apart from RStudio.  From the [Packrat walkthrough](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/walkthrough.html):

```
## Install the package from CRAN
install.packages("packrat")

## Initialize packrat
packrat::init("~/path/to/your/project")

## Later on, install some package
## It will be installed in ~/path/to/your/project/packrat/lib
install.packages("reshape2")

## Take a snapshot of installed packages
packrat::snapshot()
```

I'm probably only half-way describing the manual process.  I've only ever used the automatic mode in RStudio.  I installed it after starting a project, and it looked through my code, managed to pull all the necessary packages (not sure about versions, since I'm always at the bleeding edge), saved the source files, and installed them in my project directory.  Then I was able to move the packrat directory to another machine and have it install all the packages.

Answer (score 1):

There is a python package for the same: https://github.com/chinmayshah99/r_freeze.
Usage:

```
pip install r_freeze
```

For printing the name of packages:

```
r_freeze .
```

For creating a requirments file:

```
r_freeze -o req.txt .
```

For creating a requirments as R script:

```
r_freeze -o req.R .
```

For overwriting a requirments file:

```
r_freeze -o req.R --overwrite .
```

PS. I wrote this package due to my frustration that there doesn't exist such service for R when I myself had to generate these requirements from a huge project.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this page](https://kb.databricks.com/r/pin-r-packages.html), you can use a library snapshot of a given date (for example Microsoft stores them since 2014), that is, pass, e.g. `repos='https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-08-06/'` to `install.packages` or `devtools::install`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your problem

```
pkgLoad <- function( packages = "favourites" ) {
  
  if( length( packages ) == 1L && packages == "favourites" ) {
    packages <- c( "data.table", "chron", "plyr", "dplyr", "shiny",
                   "shinyjs", "parallel", "devtools", "doMC", "utils",
                   "stats", "microbenchmark", "ggplot2", "readxl",
                   "feather", "googlesheets", "readr", "DT", "knitr",
                   "rmarkdown", "Rcpp"
    )
  }
  
  packagecheck <- match( packages, utils::installed.packages()[,1] )
  
  packagestoinstall <- packages[ is.na( packagecheck ) ]
  
  if( length( packagestoinstall ) > 0L ) {
    utils::install.packages( packagestoinstall,
                             repos = "http://cran.csiro.au"
    )
  } else {
    print( "All requested packages already installed" )
  }
  
  for( package in packages ) {
    suppressPackageStartupMessages(
      library( package, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE )
    )
  }
  
}

## call the function
pkgLoad()
```